# Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is only compatible with the netcoreapp2.2 target framework

Tags: .net

I am working on an older .net app and trying to bring up a few parts.  I upgraded netcoreapp to 2.2.8 and it looks like AspNetCore.app does not like this version.  What version should I bring it up to so I get away from this error?

Thank you for any input

---

Severity    Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Suppression State
Error       This version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is only compatible with the netcoreapp2.2 target framework. Please target netcoreapp2.2 or choose a version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.App compatible with netcoreapp2.2.8.   UI          0

Comment: .NET Core 2.2 reached end of life a while ago, so any time spent on it now is in vain.

Comment: I understand but i need to compile this